# Why do people make the mistake of calling it a "job market?"

Tags: economy, languages

A market means that in a specific location (or via an online platform) by a consumer's own will, they can directly exchange money for goods and services while the market is operational. If someone is looking for a job, there is no guarantee of any end product or service regardless of if it is "in stock" and regardless of if they are the first to request it. And, there is no money tendered for being hired.

If you go into a grocery store and buy tomato, you don't have to wait a week while the manager looks at your qualifications for eating a tomato and then decides that someone else is more qualified to eat it or that you are more qualified to eat it over someone else. Given the two examples, it seems that "job market" is a complete misnomer for what people generalize as seeking a job from a variety of independent businesses.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63533/discussion-on-question-by-danejoe-why-do-people-make-the-mistake-of-calling-it-a).

Answer (score 14):

It's a [market in the economic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_(economics)), as in the process by which the prices of goods and services are established. (The merit - or at least the efficiency - of which is, in passing, [disputed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debunking_Economics).)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63411/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-de-bernardy-why-do-people-make-the-mistake-of-call).